# Bash: How to escape a string for use in JSON?

Tags: json, bash, jq

My Bash script has lots of variable assignments which are put in a JSON file:

```
var='Hello
    "world". 
    This is \anything \or \nothing
'
echo "{ \"var\"= \"$var\" }" > output.json
```

When validating the file `output.json` jq says:

```
$ cat output.json | jq .
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 9
```

How can I make a valid JSON file out of it? Any `\` and `"` should be preserved.

The correct JSON string would be

```
{ "var": "Hello
    \"world\". 
    This is \\anything \\or \\nothing
  " }
```

I cannot modify the variable assignments but the JSON creation.

Comment: JSON strings can not contain line feeds, your expected output is not a valid JSON value.

Comment: `echo "{\"x\":\"a\n\"}" | jq .`  is valid with a newline!

Comment: \n is an escape sequence representing line feed character, it's not a literal line feed. Your expected output contains literal line feed characters

Comment: you can use `sed` if jq is not available  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-each-newline-n-with-a-space-using-sed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `$var` as a raw string argument and JQ will automatically convert it to a valid JSON string.

```
$ jq -n --arg var "$var" '{$var}'
{
  "var": "Hello\n    \"world\". \n    This is \\anything \\or \\nothing\n"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

"*JSON strings can not contain line feeds*", as oguz ismail already mentioned, so it's better to let dedicated tools like [`xidel`](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) (or `jq`) convert the line feeds to a proper escape sequence and to valid JSON.

Stdin:

```
$ var='Hello
    "world". 
    This is \anything \or \nothing
'

$ xidel - -se '{"var":$raw}' <<< "$var"
{
  "var": "Hello\n    \"world\". \n    This is \\anything \\or \\nothing\n"
}
```

Environment variable:

```
$ export var='Hello
    "world".
    This is \anything \or \nothing
'

$ xidel -se '{"var":environment-variable("var")}'
{
  "var": "Hello\n    \"world\". \n    This is \\anything \\or \\nothing\n"
}
```